# Sleep schedule for goblins

Tags: dnd-5e, sleep, goblin

I am looking for sources on goblins' sleep schedule in D&D 5e. Do they sleep at night? Do they sleep whenever? Does the GM resolve this kind of detail?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Goblins sleep during the day

According to the lore section of the [Goblin](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-g#Goblins) entry in the *Monster Manual* on page 165:

> [...] Like rats, goblins shun sunlight and **sleep underground during the day**. [...]